# How can I deal with output from a secondary process in realtime?

Tags: .net, vb.net, perl, vb.net-2010

I am trying to write a VB .NET program that runs a Perl script and reads and uses the standard output. I'd like to be able to handle each line separately as it is printed, and update my program display accordingly. Here's some code I have "written" (read: "mostly copied off the internet"):

```
Private WithEvents pscript As Process

Private Sub myProgram_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    pscript = New Process()
    pscript.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    pscript.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\perl64\bin\perl.exe"
    pscript.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\test.pl"
    pscript.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    pscript.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    pscript.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    AddHandler pscript.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf pscript_output_process
    pscript.Start()
    pscript.BeginOutputReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub pscript_output_process(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(e.Data)
End Sub
```

This works with one problem: the program waits until the test script has run to completion, and then fires several OutputDataReceived events one after the other. This means that when I make it use the real script, it's likely to do nothing for as much as several hours, and then have to deal with, like, 5,000 events at once, despite the fact that stuff was being printed at fairly regular intervals throughout that time.

Is there any way I can make it deal with each line of text when it is written, instead of all of it at once at the end?

Comment: This is probably neither here nor there, but the help documentation states repeatedly that "The application that is processing the asynchronous output should call the WaitForExit method to ensure that the output buffer has been flushed"

Comment: Jim: A call to WaitForExit causes the application to completely freeze until the script is done, and otherwise it works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix it by copying more stuff off the internet. The problem seems to have been in Perl, which normally doesn't flush standard output after each print statement. I don't really know what that last sentence means means, but anyway, adding the line `local $| = 1;` to the top of the script (which makes it automatically flush standard output, according to a site I read) fixes the problem.

Comment: "Flush standard output" is a bit of a sloppy description. It should say "flush the buffer for STDOUT". For efficiency, by default a fast RAM buffer is used; the data are put into the stream (file, terminal, socket) only when the buffer is full or manually emptied ("flushed"). Setting [`$|`](http://p3rl.org/var#%24%7c) switches buffering off. (My explanation is a bit inaccurate, but the gist is true; not enough space here to mention the finer details.) Read [Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) for an extended discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the article. This makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
While (pscript.HasExited = False)
    Dim sLine As String = pscript.StandardOutput.ReadLine
End While
```

Comment: For some reason this only catches the first line printed, and it still waits until the script is done. Also, it causes my program to freeze while the script runs, which is why I like the event-based method (if it worked!).